# Is it safe to eat sushi with different toppings (cooked and raw) after 24h?

Tags: sushi, raw, sashimi

I have been reading posts in the internet, but it just made me more confused. My conclysions after reading several posts of different websites:

1. Some say that sushi (the rice) with sashimi (raw fish) should be safe, but the cooked food shouldn't (this fact shocked me a little bit as I would expect the opposite).
2. Others say completely the opposite, as I was expecting. Even like 16h after storing it in the fridge, if it has sashimi (raw fish) it should be thrown (depending on the freshness of the fish. If you ordered it, its impossible to know).

**Context:**

I went at a friend's place yesterday at about 22:00. We chilled (using this verb in the cooking exchange just sounds weird, sorry) for a few hours and then I went home, not without taking the enormous sushi tray that was leftovers from a few hours before I went there.

Some info:

- The sushi tray was on the table, not in the fridge. So my friends probably ate and then went to the living room without putting it inside the fridge. **Let's say 5h passed**.
- When I got home, I immediately stored it inside the fridge.
- Some sushi has raw fish (sashimi), some has cooked stuff (like japanese omelette) and I think there are some vegetarian or vegan ones.

Picture of the tray:

[image: Sushi!]

Comment: Whilst I'd never eat morning-after sushi at the best of times, right now I'd be considerably more concerned about being indoors with friends at someone else's house during the coronavirus pandemic. That's still illegal where I live, with no sign of it being lifted for at least a month.

Comment: @Tetsujin It is allowed in the country I am now, with a maximum of 10 people. We were 4, a couple, and 2 friends.

Comment: It doesn't! @moscafj I really wanted to know specifically for sushi, or raw food. Depending on the country and the kind of food, the time I guess  it changes!

Comment: @M.K  actually, it does apply.  Food pathogens don't respect international borders.  Your food was in the danger zone far too long.  The duplicate question addresses that.  I'm not criticizing your question, it's just that we already have a question that deals with this.

Comment: In a more generic way, then I guess it would definetly apply. In a generic way. @moscafj
If more people find it is the same, I'll be more than happy if it is marked as "this question already has an answer"! But probably sushi leftover edibility questions will pop up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What matters is time in the [Danger Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_zone_(food_safety)). If your sashimi heated up to room temperature it should certainly not be consumed: for instance *E. Coli* doubles in between 15 minutes and 1 hour in warm conditions. (Sushi on the same tray is likely to get cross contamination.) Chilling it later does not help: the bacteria have already grown.

A very cautious recommendation is that any food that has spent more than 2 hours above 4C should not be consumed. This is particularly important for raw fish and meat that *will* be contaminated with bacteria.

Comment: I wanted to know specifically about sushi and raw fish (or cooked ingredients on top of sushi), which is why the other question does not apply.  What you mention is really interesing (cross contamination). This is definetly a better answer than I expected. Thank you very much. I will definetly take into account your recommendation, specially with raw food.